# Bing Maps v8 Route Dragging

Tags: bing-maps

Back in Bing Maps v7, if you dragged the route to the edge of your map, it would move the map in that direction.  This saves the user from having to drop that route marker, move the map themselves, and then pick back up the marker to continue altering the route to meet their needs. For example, if you go to https://www.bingmapsportal.com/isdk/ajaxv7#DirectionsModule2, you will be able to try out this functionality.  However, if you go to http://www.bing.com/api/maps/sdkrelease/mapcontrol/isdk#directionsGetRequestOptions+JS, you will not see the map move as you drag the route to the edge of the map.

I have looked at the api for directionsRenderOptions (https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/mt750365.aspx) and directionsRequestOptions (https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/mt750373.aspx), but I don't see anything that seems related to being able to move the map as you drag a route. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe this is a scenario that will be supported in V8. Not sure if this is something that can be easily added as all the rendering happens on an HTML5 canvas in V8 and is re-rendered when it moves. Will add a feature request for this for the team to look into.

Comment: Awesome, thank you.  Just found it weird when we used to be able to do that and I could no longer seem to use that functionality.

Comment: The directions module went through a major overhaul as it was overly complicated in V7 and we had a lot of negative feedback about it. There has also been a few new features added which make customizations a bit difficult at the moment.